# Find an XML element in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

How do I find an element by it's name ( not by references like: first(); last(); parent() ) in XML soap response?

```
<xyzOrderReturn>
  <xyzOrderResponse>
    <UlidList>
        <Ulid ExtnUlid="1-222-333">
            <OrderList TotalRecords="0"/>
        </Ulid>
    </UlidList>
  </xyzOrderResponse>
</xyzOrderReturn>
```

This is what I tried for 'xyzOrderResponse', but none is working...

```
  def result = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

  def element1 = result.breadthFirst()*.findAll { it.name() == 'xyzOrderResponse' }
  def element2 = result.depthFirst().findAll { it.name() == 'xyzOrderResponse' }

     println element1
     println element2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those work, they just don't show when you print the list, but the list has size 1 and:

```
def result = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

def element1 = result.breadthFirst().findAll { it.name() == 'xyzOrderResponse' }
def element2 = result.depthFirst().findAll { it.name() == 'xyzOrderResponse' }

println element1*.name()
println element2*.name()
```

prints

```
[xyzOrderResponse]
[xyzOrderResponse]
```

You can also replace the depthFirst variant with:

```
def element2 = result.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'xyzOrderResponse' }
```

Comment: Thanks!! Is there anyway to trim out [] from the output?

Comment: Sure, use `find` instead of `findAll` to return a single element instead of a list.

Comment: Ok. we can remove the square brackets by .replaceAll("[\\\[\\\]]","")

Comment: I am planning to compare the result with another string. Ex:
     log =  element1*.name()
     def result = log.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","")

     String svc = "xyzOrderResponse"
     if (svc != result) { send email notification.execute() }

Comment: Yeah, just use `find` to get a single element. Don't use `findAll` to get a list, convert that into a string and then hack the string. `find` and `element.name()` is the way forward